# how to run some specific sampler only once?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

[image]

I have login sampler which i just want to run only once to get cookies but other sampler in Thread Group 2 will run multiple times.

Currently when i run plan it run Login also multiple times. How to config Login sampler to run only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to put the sampler under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), this way it will be executed only during first [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration

If your criteria are more complex - go for [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) where you can specify custom and even multiple conditions for executing the child(ren) sampler(s)

Comment: thanks. i used once only controller and its working as required.